# How to pass a param to a factory in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my service:

```
    app.factory('ApiStoreService', function ($q) {

        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

            new SwaggerApi({
                discoveryUrl: "https://apiurl",
                apiKeyName : "apiKey",
                apiKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
                success: function () {
                    resolve(this);
                }
            });
        }) 
    });
```

which I call this way:

```
ApiStoreService.then(function (store) {// do something with store}
```

I want to pass the hardcoded values as parameters. What's the best way to achieve this in angular?

Comment: Create an object with some functions on it and return that object from factory. That way you can pass parameters.

Comment: This post might give you a clue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561989/angularjs-factory-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    app.factory('ApiStoreService', function ($q) {
    return{
        DoFunction: function(value){
            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

                new SwaggerApi({
                    discoveryUrl: "https://apiurl",
                    apiKeyName : "apiKey",
                    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
                    success: function () {
                        resolve(this);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    }
});
```

and use it like this:

```
var Obj = { name:'tim'};
ApiStoreService.DoFunction(Obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess Angular Constants/Value would serve the purpose and please read the below gist,
https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099